# Same application open on other application shortcut icon

Tags: android

I have create a shortcut icon on home after installing other apps. I am able to add shortcut icon on home but after click on shortcut icon, only my application is open.

My code:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context,
                        list.get(i).activityInfo.name.getClass());
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,
                     manager.getApplicationLabel(list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, list.get(i).activityInfo.icon);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

list type is ResolveInfo.